# LinkedIn Ads AdAnalyticsV2: Internal Server Error

Tags: linkedin-api

Getting the error when fetching ad analytics from the API. The URL used: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics`

Other URL options sent along with the request (dummy account ID used):

```
{
  'accounts[0]': 'urn:li:sponsoredAccount:1234'
  'dateRange.start.year': 2017,
  'dateRange.start.month': 12,
  'dateRange.start.day': 1,
  'dateRange.end.year': 2017,
  'dateRange.end.month': 12,
  'dateRange.end.day': 22,
  timeGranularity: 'DAILY',
  pivot: [ 'MEMBER_JOB_TITLE' ] 
}
```

So the full request becomes:
`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&accounts[0]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:1234&dateRange.start.year=2017&dateRange.start.month=12&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.end.year=2017&dateRange.end.month=12&dateRange.end.day=22&timeGranularity=DAILY&pivot=MEMBER_JOB_TITLE`

This request worked earlier today, but now it returns an Internal Server Error. Does anyone else have this issue or know what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be trying to pass in the options in the request body. To use the Ad Analytics API, you will need to pass in the options as query parameters in a GET request:

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange.start.month=12&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.year=2017&timeGranularity=DAILY&pivot=MEMBER_JOB_TITLE&accounts[0]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:1234`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately that's exactly what I do. Just formatted it as an object for clarity. Will update my original post to reflect this better.